# ReportBuilder 15 with Delphi XE4: Reports are empty

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4, reportbuilder

I am migrating my code from Delphi 7 (ReportBuilder 12) to Delphi XE4 Enterpirse (ReportBuilder 15). To my wonder, when I click on Preview button to see load the reports, reports are appearing empty while in delphi 7 reports are showing data.

I don't think there is any error with code because its running fine there in Delphi 7. Is there any setting/configuration missing on my end? What and where should I check for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not a reportbuilder issue but database issue. Infact the application which I migrated to Delphi XE4, was not able to pick data from database, that's why report were showing empty.

Answer (score 1):

That is quite a version leap you are making here: Delphi 7 to XE4 and RB12 to RB15!

I would compile Reportbuilder15 with debug info and trace what is happening in RB, because i think there are so many places where something is changed, it is close to impossible to pinpoint one specific place to look.

Comment: I am trying myself to figure it out. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: @npk It would be helpful to others if you would post the solution in here if you found it